# Can I answer my own question which was asked with another account of mine?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I know that if I have two Stack Overflow accounts and use one to upvote another, this is cheating, what if I ask a question with an account and answer this question with another account? Is this counted as cheating? Can I accept my own answer?

Comment: You earn some rep from it, don't you?

Comment: @rene I think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should not do this. But **thanks** for asking first. (+1)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Yes, I won't :)

Comment: If you are trying to share knowledge, it is perfectly fine to ask and answer a question using the same account.

Comment: that would be consider as a spam I believe :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> - someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation and the author of the accepted answer earns +15 reputation.
> - your own answer: No reputation is awarded, and the answer does not float to the top of the list. You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.
> - a community-wiki answer: No reputation is awarded.

So using two accounts to interact with any of your own posts I would call that fraud and is unfair for users like me with just one account.

Comment: Wait, *just* one account? ;)

Answer (score 6):

That would *not* be a good idea. Accepting the answer would award reputation to *both* your accounts (+2 to the asker, +15 for the answerer).

Moreover, people may judge answers by what *looks* like an independent account differently from a self-answer. As such your answer may receive a different number of votes from what it would get otherwise.

Don't do *anything* with a second account you cannot do with just one.

Comment: Got it, I upvoted your answer and will accept another :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be doing it as it will fail the purpose. if you can answer with the same account and mark it as an answer that will be more appreciated by the users and if the answer is a hit you can earn more repo rather than working with two different accounts